# Generalisation of idempotent matrices to higher powers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, idempotents

Does there exist a species of matrix, say $M$, such that

$$M^{\alpha} = M, \quad M \neq I$$

for some $\alpha > 2$. I'm not looking for idempotent matrices (square to themselves), but in essence a kind of generalisation of them.

A construction I considered was by isomorphism - the involutive matrices are isomorphic to the idempotent so I wondered if there was a similar isomorphism between matrices of general finite order and the ones I seek above. So far, I haven't found such a thing.

Comment: How are involutions and idempotents are "isomorphic"?

Comment: If $A$ is an idempotent, then $I - 2A$ is involutive. Moreover, if $B$ is involutive, then $1/2(I + B)$ is idempotent.

Comment: they can be characterized by those diagonalizable matrices with all eigenvalues satisfying $\lambda^\alpha=\lambda$

Comment: Matrices over which ring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is often called a ***periodic*** matrix.

A common example is any $(3\times 3)$ normalized $(\|N\|^2_F = 2)$  skew-symmetric $(N^T = -N)$ matrix.

Such a matrix is rank deficient $({\rm rank}(N)=2)$ and its nullspace consists of a single vector $(n\implies Nn=0)$, which is usually normalized $(\|n\|^2={\tt1})$.

Here is its multiplication table
$$\eqalign{
N^2 &= nn^T-I \\
N^3 &= -N \\
N^4 &= I-nn^T \\
N^5 &= N \\
}$$
This table can be represented by a variety of
formulas $(k\ge 0)$
$$\eqalign{
\def\o{{\tt1}}
N^{k+3} &= -N^{k+1} \\
N^{2k+1} &= (-\o)^{k}N \\
N^{2k+2} &= (-\o)^{k}N^2 \\
N^{4k+1} &= N \\
}$$

Another recipe for constructing a periodic matrix is to use a permutation matrix $P$ as the leading diagonal block and a zero matrix as the lower diagonal block, e.g.
$$B = \pmatrix{
P & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
}$$
This matrix will have the same period as $P$ but $B^k\ne I$ for all $k\ge\o$.